# Performing wait/sleep activities in Akka actors

Tags: akka

Is there any issue if I have to do a sleep/wait activity inside an actor, like say taking from a blocking queue?

My use case:
We are implementing a basic ETL that is fed data from heterogeneous sources (file, sms, email). We have source specific receivers, that can trigger an extract-transform-load sequence flow on events. We are orchestrating the flow using Akka actors (mainly to achieve parallelism and fault handling/retrial).

For file and email, which are "pull" receivers, a new flow is triggered on event receipt. For sms, which is a "push" receiver, we plan to have a single flow, whose extractor would be listening on a durable queue, and the receiver would actually queue on event receipt.

We are using fork-join dispatcher and single e-t-l actors.

Comment: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0-RC1/general/actor-systems.html#Blocking_Needs_Careful_Management